# Google Cloud Certificate provisioning_failed but domain active - Serverless NEG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase

1. I have firebase functions (Google Cloud Functions) that work on their https://.cloudfunctions.net/.
2. I have created a HTTPS Load Balancer with a Serverless NEG, Created SSL certificate (Google Managed).
3. I have enabled both HTTP and HTTPS as Certificate provisioning keeps failing (provisioning_failed) but domain is active. HTTP works i.e. I can access the function and it works.
4. I created another sub-domain with another function with the same load balancer and Certificate provisioning was successful after quite a few minutes.
5. First one is . and second one is called .. Status works but however the api subdomain continues to have certificate generation issues.
6. I do not have api with another CNAMES (Cloud Run) although I have used both cloud run and App Engine recently for the api subdomain.

I believe certificate generation for the api subdomain is my issue and perhaps I may've hit rate limits. I need this sub-domain working ASAP. How can I get this moving quick?

Best
Ukor

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new certificate via the GCP Load Balancers with an additional domain as a workaround for certificate creation limits.

Hopefully I never come to these limits again.